# Difference between self.navigationController.navigationItem and self.navigationItem

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

What is the difference between self.navigationController.navigationItem and self.navigationItem?  I am using a UINavigationController throughout the app and when I use self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems, in one of the viewDidLoad methods of one of the viewControllers, the array is empty.  However if I use self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems, I see my bar button items.  What is the difference between the two calls?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `UINavigationController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`. As such, it has its own independent `navigationItem` property, which it inherited from `UIViewController`. You should ignore this property, as it would only be used if you were to embed a navigation controller inside another navigation controller (which nobody in their right mind would ever do).

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `UIViewController+UINavigationControllerItem`, see below, we should be using the `navigationItem` property directly on the view controller:

```
// Created on-demand so that a view controller may customize its navigation appearance.
@property(nonatomic,readonly,strong) UINavigationItem *navigationItem;
```

`UINavigationController` also has a `navigationItem` property since it's inheriting from `UIViewController`, but setting it won't affect the view controller's navigation properties.

From a quick test, we can see that these navigation items are not equal either:

```
(lldb) po self.navigationItem
<UINavigationItem: 0x7f865c99ec50>

(lldb) expr -- @import UIKit
(lldb) po self.navigationController.navigationItem
<UINavigationItem: 0x7f865c811740>
```